# Register an exe file as OLE server with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, ole, regsvr32

I want to register an EXE file as OLE server with Inno Setup.
When I use my EXE file path with Regserver parameter in `cmd`, everything is correct.

But when I use the `regserver` flag in Inno Setup like this:

```
Source: "{src}\App\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external regserver
```

I got this error

> Unable to register the DLL/OCX: Regsvr32 failed with exit code 0x4.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`regserver` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=regserver) is for DLL/OCX files only. There's no standard way to register EXE files, so it cannot be handled natively by Inno Setup, the same way you cannot use `regsvr32` with an EXE file.

If your EXE file has a custom command-line parameter for the registration, use it in Inno Setup in the [`Run` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Parameters: "Regserver"
```